# How to activate and deactivate animation based on scrolling into the viewport and scrolling out of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to create some animation effect when scrolling into and out of the viewport. When the user scrolls until the block comes into the viewport, the animation activates(a paragraph comes in from the bottom (slide in effect)),  and when the user scrolls out of it, another kind of animation activates (the paragraph goes out to the upper side  (slide out effect)), and if the user decide to scroll back to the block, the slide in effect activates again. 
An example is [www.allbirds.com](http://www.allbirds.com), I want to have the same animation as the second block, the paragraph that start with "The secret to creating the most comfortable".

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/basurayu/5RNhL/667/) that I created using animated.css and some code from another question, it activates once when you scroll down, but it does not activate again when I scroll back once I scroll pass it, I also want to create "bounceOutUp" effect when I pass the block, how can I do that? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport.
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);

    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
    var $elem = $('.animatedblock .movingpicture');

    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('animated')) return;

    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('animated');
         $elem.addClass('bounceInUp');
    }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation();
});
```

Comment: You can check if the scroll reach the top of a section by using js element.offset().top